# Get n random rows from mysql and write them to file

Tags: php, mysql

I need to take n random rows from mysql table and write them to file . Please help me how could I do it using php? Structure of mysql table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keys` (
  `keyword` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Please, show us your approach

Comment: What do you mean by "first" rows?

Comment: You don’t have any “first” rows until you define a sorting criterion first.

Comment: I'll change my question: how could I get random unique rows from table and write them to file?

Comment: @user2963041 Update the question and title then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that by `first n` rows you meant the first N alphabetically, your code shoud be something like:

```
$fd = fopen("/the/filename/you/want","w");
$db = new mysqli($host,$username,$passwd,$dbname);
$rs = $db->query("SELECT `keyword` FROM `keys` order by `keyword` LIMIT $n"); //Being $n the number of rows that you want
while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
{
  fwrite($fd,$row['keyword']);
}
$rs->free();
fclose($fd);
```